# CFString doesn't conform to protocol Hashable?

Tags: xcode, swift, ios8, xcode6.1, hashable

I recently updated to Xcode 6.1 to be able to work with iOS 8.1, but now my latest project in facing an error.

I get the error saying that "CFString! does not conform to protocol Hashable", for the following line:

```
let attributes = [kCTForegroundColorAttributeName:UIColor.blackColor().CGColor, kCTFontAttributeName: font]
```

I did not get this error when running Xcode 6.0.1. And also, Xcode 6.1 is extremely slow. I mean, so slow that it doesn't actually finish loading anything. Indexing takes several minutes, and building takes so long that I haven't managed to sit through... It also crashes.

My main problem is with the Hashable protocol though. What's up with that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This appears to be a type inference bug with Dictionaries that contain CF objects.

The compiler is (apparently) using the first key/value pair to infer a Dictionary of type `[CFStringRef:CGColorRef]`, and then fails to compile because `CFStringRef` doesn't conform to `Hashable`.

You can work around the problem by explicitly declaring the Dictionary type:

```
let attributes : [String:AnyObject] = [
    kCTForegroundColorAttributeName:UIColor.blackColor().CGColor, 
    kCTFontAttributeName:font
]
```

Comment: Thanks... solved my issue after half an hour of trial and error